# List View Alignment

Tags: android, listview

How do I move the list view slightly right. I used ListView to populate menu and price as per image below. The menu start at the edge of the screen. How do I adjust so the menu starts slightly right instead start from the edge of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_sheet">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="ABC Restoran Full Menu"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#333300"
       ></TextView>
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        >
        <ListView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ListView_ProfileMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            ></ListView>
         <ListView
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ListView_ProfileMenu1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@null"           
            ></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try to set **Left-Padding="2dp"** for that in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by adding **Padding** to your **RelativeLayout** which contains *ListView*.

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

**Just for the record, you shouldn't use two separate ListViews to show records in pair (name & price). You may use single ListView to achieve this*

Answer (score 0):

Either use Padding or Margins on your ListView in your layout.
Below is an example which uses a margin to move it over 20dp from the left

```
<ListView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ListView_ProfileMenu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:divider="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" and android:layout_marginRight="10dp" to your relative layout and listview..